# After adding a external script how to read the response of the URL of the source?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Here is the sample code.

```
var s=document.createElement("script");
s.src="http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

After executing the last line there will be a get request.
And the response will be 200 , How can I read the response of this request.

Comment: Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: I know that
For cross domain I can't make the ajax request.
By this way I can make the request with status 200.

Comment: The Same-Origin Policy specifically means you can't read the response.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't get the actual respone, you can set `s.onerror` and `s.onload` to determine whether or not it loaded successfully.

```js
function importScript (sSrc, fOnload) {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
    oScript.onerror = loadError;
    if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
    document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(oScript, document.currentScript);
    oScript.src = sSrc;
}

function loadError (oError) {
  alert("The script " + oError.target.src + " is not accessible.");
}

importScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js", function() { alert("It Worked"); });
importScript("https://example.com/broken.js", function() { alert("It Worked"); });
```

If you do need to get the actual response, you will probably need to set up a proxy, so that you can hit something like `https://your-own-server.com/getJsonFrom?src=http://example.com` and then you can have your *server* do the request, and then you are reading the response from your own server.

Or, if you have control over the other server, you can have it return, instead of

```
{ some: "data" }
```

it would instead return

```
callback({ some:  "data" });
```

and then you can define `callback` to do whatever you want with it:

```
function callback(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is if the script returned from that url calls you back. 
Usually it's achieved with a function name parameter, such as callback.

For example:
image you have on your site

```
window.globalCallback = (data) => alert(data)
```

if GET http://example.com?callback=globalCallback returned a javascript file such as:

```
globalCallback("some data");
```

Then you would get "some data" alerted to you.
That's jsonp in a nutshell.